# file upload from Flask template to external APIs

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

- I have divided my flask app with two-part API (Flask API) and web app (Flask template).
- From the web app, I am trying to upload a file but on the API side, I am not able to send.
- File upload is working from APIs side, I have tested from the postman.
- Template (UI with port: 3010) and API (port: 3009)

### Below is running on API side with port 3009

```
@app.route('/sources', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            print(request.form.get('file')) # Not able to print file here
            print(request.form.get('Language1'))  # I am able to print it
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file part in the request'})
                resp.status_code = 400
                return resp             
            file = request.files['file']
            if file.filename == '':
                resp = jsonify({'message' : 'No file selected for uploading'})
                resp.status_code = 400
                return resp
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename,'sources'):
                sourceFileName = secure_filename(file.filename)
                Lang1 = request.form.get('Language1')
                Lang2 = request.form.get('Language2')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            resp = jsonify({'message' : 'Server Error'})
            resp.status_code = 500
            return resp
```

### Below is running on UI side with port 3010

```
@app.route('/sources', methods=['POST'])
def upload_sources():
    if request.method == "POST":
        Language1 = request.form["Language1"]
        Language2 = request.form["Language2"]
        file = request.files["file"]
        # File object is printing here like: [<FileStorage: 'source_text.docx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')>]
        print(file) 
        params = {
                  "Language1":Language1,
                  "Language2":Language2,
                  "file":file
                 }
        headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
        req = requests.post('http://localhost:3009/sources', headers=headers, data=params)
        r = req.json()
        print(r['message']) # I am getting response message : ['No file part in the request']

    return redirect(url_for('fetch_sources'))
```

### Below is working fine, just fetching uploaded file

```
@app.route('/sources', methods=['GET'])
def fetch_sources():
    sources = requests.get('http://localhost:3009/sources')
    source_data = sources.json()
    if source_data:
        return render_template('sources.html', sources=source_data['sources'])
```

Comment: post request from webapp to API, I am getting file object as below:   
```ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'only_story.docx' (None)>)]) ```

And post request from postman to API, I am getting as below:
```ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'only_story.docx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')>)])```
Kindly give me suggestion so that I can solve my issue..
I want same file object from webapp to API as well................

Answer (score 0):

I was sending a file object and the way which I was following that was incorrect...

I can not send file directly to API from webapp.
Here I have changed my code and it is working fine.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    file = request.files["file"]
    sourceFileName = secure_filename(file.filename)
    cwd = os.getcwd()+'/'
    if 'temp' not in os.listdir(cwd):
        os.mkdir(cwd + 'temp')
    file.save(os.path.join(cwd + 'temp', sourceFileName))

    with open(cwd + 'temp/'+ sourceFileName, 'rb') as f:
        data_file = ImmutableMultiDict([("file", f)])
        resp = requests.post(api_base_url + "/sources",
                             files=data_file)
```